# How can I avoid succubi?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm finding the homing shot of succubi quite annoying and I'd rather avoid damage if possible.  I still haven't figured out how to avoid getting hit by it, and now that I'm in Hell, the damage is no longer ignorable.

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do differently?  I'm asking specifically for barbarian, but answers covering all classes are preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you are looking for high mobility abilities. The shots they fire are very slow to move, and very slow to turn. Off the top of my head:

- [Leap](http://d3db.com/skill/i/leap) for barbarians.
- [Vault](http://d3db.com/skill/i/vault) or [Smoke Screen](http://d3db.com/skill/i/smoke-screen) for Demon Hunters.
- [Thunderclap rune](http://d3db.com/runestone/i/fists-of-thunder/a) for Monks can work well.
- [Teleport](http://d3db.com/skill/i/teleport) for wizards.
- [Spirit Walk](http://d3db.com/skill/i/spirit-walk) for Witch Doctors.

In particular, the teleport style spells can work really well if you move directly to the other side of the ball. By the time it turns around to get to you it will have disappeared.

For melee classes, it works best if you kill off other stuff first, avoiding the bullets. If you can avoid the bullets successfully, the succubi don't do much damage themselves while you're under their effect. The bullets are near impossible to dodge at melee range. If you find you can't successfully dodge them, save your defensive cooldowns for when you get hit and try to smash them down first before trying to work through other things, but seeing as they are flying creatures they can be a pain to keep down in one place with other mobs in the area.

Comment: Spirit Walk for witch doctors

Comment: @StrixVaria: Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

What everyone else said, but in addition, you can stop the projectiles by having it hit a wall. Run around a corner and it will disappear after hitting the wall!

Answer (score 3):

Ranged classes generally shouldn't have much of a problem avoiding succubi missiles, seeing how they really move pretty slowly and the homing function isn't that hard of a gimmick to get over (they move really slowly for projectiles)

DHs have vault, smokescreen to avoid.
Wiz's have mirror images, teleport, armors
Witch docs have spirit walk, and usually its the minions soaking up the missiles anyway.

For melee classes though, there's really no two way around about it, either stack up your resists / hp till they stop becoming a bother, pop your defensive cooldowns when engaging a group of them, or keep them crowd-controlled. You're bound to get hit by the missiles when you solo, because you got to be in their face when you're pounding on them. If you're in a group, just let the range get them down while you avoid the missiles with leap, charge, and etc.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the defensive abilities for Wizards listed above, you can also use Wave of Force to repel the succubi's projectiles. Hitting a Wave of Force will reflect the succubi's projectile away (assuming it's in range) from the Wizard, and if you line it up right it will return to the succubus damaging them.